# Why is this image/ image element size 0px?

Tags: jquery, css

I've got this image tag:

```
<img id="sidebar" src="images/homepageSidebar.jpeg" style="max-height:800px; float:left; padding-left:10px;"/>
```

I'm trying to get the images width so I can place text next to it.  When I do the following function I get a sidebarWidth of 0px:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var sidebarWidth = $('#sidebar').width(),
        introPosition = sidebarWidth + 10;

    $('#intro').css({ left:introPosition });

    console.log(sidebarWidth);
    console.log(introPosition);

});
```

Does anyone see what my mistake is?  Thanks.

Comment: Your image url is not correct, maybe the iamge is not loaded.

Comment: @Trung-HieuLe, that was a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(document).ready` fires when the DOM is built but before all resources are loaded, like images. You'll have to use the `window.load` event.

```
$(window).on('load', function (){
    var sidebarWidth = $('#sidebar').width(),
        introPosition = sidebarWidth + 10;

  $('#intro').css({ left:introPosition });

  console.log(sidebarWidth);
  console.log(introPosition);

});
```

Comment: that suggestion worked.  I also added `position:'absolute'` to the .css method.